# Code first gRPC client generation problem in ASP.NET

Tags: c#, dependency-injection, grpc, code-first, grpc-c#

I have followed this [microsoft tutorial](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/grpc/code-first?view=aspnetcore-7.0) to create gRPC service and client.
Now i have problem with generating gRPC client class.

To get data i use this method, but i doesn't seem right. I wish I could inject client using AddGrpcClient but i can't find any generated client gRPC classes.

```
using var channel = GrpcChannel.ForAddress("http://localhost:5053");
var client = channel.CreateGrpcService<IFullProjectInfoService>();

var reply = await client.GetFullProjectInfoAsync(
    new FullProjectInfoRequest { ProjectId = 1, UserId = 1 }
);
```

Answer (score 0):

To inject the client using dependency injection, you could use the `AddCodeFirstGrpcClient` function, as it is documented in the [Register client service](https://protobuf-net.github.io/protobuf-net.Grpc/registerClientService.html) section of protobuf.net.

For your example it would look something like:

```cs
services.AddCodeFirstGrpcClient<IFullProjectInfoService>(o =>
{
    o.Address = new Uri("http://localhost:5053");
});
```